# Como puedo cambiar la primera columna de una tabla por la ultima en Responsive Design

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap

Como puedo cambiar la primera columna de una tabla por la ultima columna en tamaño celular, la tabla en su versión **Desktop** se debe mostrar como la **imagen adjunta**, lo que quiero es que la columna **ID** se pueda cambiar por la columna **Acciones** en mobile, no puede ser por `HTML`, no se si eso se pueda con ***`CSS`***, estoy usando **Angular 9**.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table striped="true" responsive="true" class="d-block d-md-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Entidad bancaria</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Número de cuenta</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha reporte</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Valor</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Saldo</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Bancolombia S.A.</td>
      <td class="text-right">112159932</td>
      <td class="text-center">10/12/2014</td>
      <td class="text-right">267,060.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">78,610.00</td>
      <td class="text-center table__action">
        <h1>Algo</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente es algo muy sencillo, solo necesitas:

- Obtener todas las filas de la tabla (o de varias tablas) por clase
- Recorrer cada fila
- Por asignación ternaria, verificar si es TBODY o THEAD y seleccionar celdas TD o TH, respectivamente
- Usar `insertBefore()` para colocar la primera celda antes de la última, sabiendo que, a pesar de ser `insert` no se va a copiar, solo se va a mover de su ubicación actual porque no se está clonando.

```js
// Obtener todas las filas de la tabla
let trs = document.querySelectorAll('.d-md-table tr');
// Recorrer cada fila
trs.forEach(tr => {
    // Obtener celdas, si pertenecen a TBODY
    let cells = (tr.parentNode.tagName == 'TBODY')
        // Buscar todas las TD
        ? tr.querySelectorAll('td')
        // Si no es TBODY, obtener todas las TH
        : tr.querySelectorAll('th');
    // Mover la primera celda e insertarla una antes de la última
    tr.insertBefore(cells[0], cells[cells.length - 1]);
});
```

```html
<table striped="true" responsive="true" class="d-block d-md-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Entidad bancaria</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Número de cuenta</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha reporte</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Valor</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">Saldo</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Bancolombia S.A.</td>
      <td class="text-right">112159932</td>
      <td class="text-center">10/12/2014</td>
      <td class="text-right">267,060.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">78,610.00</td>
      <td class="text-center table__action">
        <h1>Algo</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### ¿Qué falta?

Detectar en qué momento realizar el cambio. Probablemente convenga escuchar cuando se carga el DOM y/o cambios en el tamaño de la ventana y ejecutar el código cuando detectes determinada resolución.

Comment: He leido que se puede hacer con hostListener @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) pero me queda la duda de que siempre se este ejecutando el resize.

Comment: @zerokira, no, porque vas a analizar el ancho de la pantalla y solo lo haces cuando se cumpla la condición que especifiques.